# Is it possible to use boost library in visual studio 2008 64 bit version?

Tags: c++, boost, 64-bit

I tried to use boost library in 64 bit mode of VS2008 but I'm getting "header file not found" errors.
is it any possible to use boost library under 64 bit mode of VS2008?
it worked fine in 32 bit mode. that's why I'm suspicuous bout 64 but ;(
Or anybody have good link to show setting up 64 bit mode to use boost?

thanks

Comment: Which header file is missing?

Comment: Yeah, of all the things in the world I would not expect a "header not found" to be a 32/64 bit difference...

Comment: It might - some of the Boost libraries include platform-specific headers. That's typically done through logic similar to #ifdef __X #include <boost/internal/foo__X.h> #elif __Y ... 

Of course, the actual filename would help...

Comment: thank you guys all. it was include directory problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost works fine with VS2008. Are you sure you have your include paths set up correctly?

I usually a reference to the boost libraries to the Options|Projects and Solutions|VC++ Directories settings. Make sure you set the "Include Files" setting for both win32 and x64.

Most of the libraries are header only and it doesn't matter if you're building 32-bit or 64-bit.